# How to change menu links items title programitically?

Tags: theming, hooks, navigation

I have created a menu name `My Menu` (machine name: my_menu ) with menu item `My Nodes` and `My messages`. Now I want alter `My nodes` and `My messages` link title. So the menu items should look like `Nodes` and `Messages` instead of `My nodes` and `My Messages`.

So I don't understand and also didn't find how can I alter the menu link title programmatically. i am trying to use `hook_menu_alter(&$items)` and `hook_menu_link_alter(&$item)`, but it doesn't give any result.

So can anyone please tell me how can I alter the menu link items title?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using D7 or D8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [theme_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_link/7.x) function for altering your link markup. I have recently come across a scenario where I needed to change my account name to user name I did with the following code.

```
function THEMENAME_link($variables) {
  if ($variables['text'] == "My account") {
    $variables['text'] = $GLOBALS['user']->name;
  }

return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . '>' . ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</a>';
}
```